# use string vector elements to refer to variable names in r

Tags: r, string, paste

I have list of variable names in a vector of strings `v` and a data table `my.dt` that contains all these variables.

```
> v
```

[1] "var1"  "var2"  "var3"

I want to use those variables whose names are in the vector v, such that i create new variable that is cbind of these 3, or any number of names that appear in v, like:

```
  new <- cbind(my.dt[,"var1"],my.dt[,"var2"],my.dt[,"var3"])
new1 <- rowSums(new, na.rm=TRUE) * ifelse(rowSums(is.na(new)) == ncol(new), NA, 1)
```

How can i get this, having in mind that number of variables is not fixed, so i dont want to refer to each element like v[1], v[2] etc.

Comment: Perhaps `my.dt[, v]` ?

Comment: i dont think its working...

Comment: And you didn't provide a reproducible example, so guessing is the only thing I can do.

Comment: For example, this small example produces the same error to me:my.dt = data.table(
        ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
        a = 1:6,
        b = 7:12,
        c = 13:18
      )
      
      v <- c("a", "ID")
      my.dt[, v]

Comment: No one knows you are working on a `data.table` because you did not mention it. The quality of your post is poor. Next time, please provide relevant information and reproducible example so others can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are working on a `data.table`. You will need to add `with = FALSE` to the code as follows.

```
library(data.table)

my.dt <- data.table( ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18 ) 
v <- c("a", "ID") 

my.dt[, v, with = FALSE]
#    a ID
# 1: 1  b
# 2: 2  b
# 3: 3  b
# 4: 4  a
# 5: 5  a
# 6: 6  c
```

Notice that if you are working on a data frame, you don't need `with = FALSE`.

```
my.dt <- data.frame( ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18 ) 
v <- c("a", "ID") 

my.dt[, v]
#   a ID
# 1 1  b
# 2 2  b
# 3 3  b
# 4 4  a
# 5 5  a
# 6 6  c
```